# Позициионирование

Tags: html, css

есть код,

```html
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
  <img src="image/logo.png" alt="Whitesquare logo">
  <img src="image/форма.png" alt="" >

  </header>
  <nav></nav>
  <div id="heading"></div>
  <aside></aside>
  <section></section>
 </div>
 <footer></footer>


</div>
</lu>
</body>
</html>
```

как задать позиционирование отдельно для каждой картинки ?

Comment: можно добавить классы им и написать css правила для классов

Comment: можно пример ? я просто новичок

Comment: а как картинки должны располагаться, одна снизу другой, одна справа от другой, или как?

Comment: не важно как, мне просто интересно как позициионировать изображения, например одна после другой с отступом

Answer (score 0):

```
<img class="img-class" src="image/logo.png" alt="Whitesquare logo">
    <img class="img-class" src="image/форма.png" alt="">
```

Вместо img-class можешь вообще любой класс поставить. Потом в файле стилей(что-то типа style.css) пропиши отдельно стиль для каждого класса

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* это файл со стилями, расширение .css */

.img1 {
  /* тут стили первой картинки */
}

.img2 {
  /* тут стили второй картинки, например отступ 100px слева */
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <img class="img1" src="https://placehold.it/200x200">
  <img class="img2" src="https://placehold.it/70x70">
</div>
```